# Macbook Pro Retina OSX 10.8.3 - Itunes - Windows 7 PC

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, windows

I have been a PC guy for 35 years. I just recently got a MacBook Pro Retina. I have well over a terabyte of MP3's on several hard drives on my Windows 7 PC. All of the files are legal rips from my vast collection of CD's. Is it possible for ITunes to play my MP3's from my Win7 PC if I share the folders?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to share the PC folders and get ITunes on the Mac to play them. All is good!

Comment: Why don't share what you've figured out so someone else in your situation could learn from it?